# How to grant select (read only) privilege to view all users and roles in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, admin, roles

Environment: Neo4j 3.5.6 Enterprise

I am trying to create a user and grant it read only access to view all users/roles and list all configuration settings. How can I do this without granting it the native admin role? Admin role has the capability to create and delete user, I don't want this full privilege to be granted to the account.

This link here https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/procedures/ indicates dbms.security.listUsers is executable by role admin. Can I grant specific procedures to a custom user/role?

```
neo4j> call dbms.listConfig('dbms.security.auth_enabled');
Permission denied.
neo4j> call dbms.security.listUsers;
Permission denied.
neo4j> call dbms.security.listRoles;
Permission denied.
```